# Get class path from class name

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm developing a platform like Netbeans but I'm facing a problem. I want to get all possible classes from class name same when pressing `Alt + Enter` in Netbeans:

[image: Example: Conncetion class]

I want to get all possible classes that have "Connection" name and put them in an array of Strings.

Comment: you can use reflection api to get it

Comment: I found similar but it got the path of current class